# How to manually add connection info to a cystal report in c#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a form containing a crystal report viewer and I have a crystal report. The crystal report has no dataconnection, no datasource because I have made connections to my database manually. (by writing code for everything)
I want to display data in my report. How do I set the connection info for the report to the one's I have in my form. ie. myDataset, myCon etc.

P.S: I am extremely new to Crystal Reports. I looked at the tutorial but that uses the crystal report wizard to make the connection.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I put my connection strings inside Configuration.AppSettings.

```
CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource1 = new CrystalReportSource();
CrystalReportViewer CrystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalReportViewer();

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReportSource1;
CrystalReportViewer1.EnableParameterPrompt = false;
CrystalReportSource1.Report.FileName = "Report3.rpt";
CrystalReportSource1.EnableCaching = false;

CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, ponumber);
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, receiptno);



TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportServerName"];
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportDatabaseName"];
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportUserID"];
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportPassword"];

TableLogOnInfos infos = new TableLogOnInfos();
infos.Add(logOnInfo);
CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo = infos;

maindiv.Controls.Add(CrystalReportSource1);
maindiv.Controls.Add(CrystalReportViewer1);


CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't have the CrystalReportSource in the intellisense under CrystalReports ???

Comment: using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Web;  (you might have to install the Crystal run times)

Comment: This might help:  http://computer-programming-forum.com/67-vb-crystal-report/c441c4b46b242ec4.htm